# How to push the item inside array in Descending order mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, aggregation

My model is

```
channel: [
    {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: 'Channel',
    },
  ],
```

I need to push id inside it

```
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.userId,
        {
          $push: {
            channel: channel._id,
          },
        },
        {
          new: true,
        }
  ).populate('channel')
```

But if i push in this way, the id is stored in ascending order, but i need to be stored in Descending order. I mean last to first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `$push` at the beginning of the array using the [`$position`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/position/) modifier:

```
await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.params.userId,
  {
    $push: {
      channel: {
        $each: [channel._id],
        $position: 0,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    new: true,
  }
);
```